# How can I create a route constraint of type System.Guid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to map a route which requires two guids?

ie. http://blah.com/somecontroller/someaction/{firstGuid}/{secondGuid}

where both firstGuid and secondGuid are not optional and must be of type system.Guid?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Create a RouteConstraint like the following:

```
public class GuidConstraint : IRouteConstraint {

public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
{
    if (values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
    {
        string stringValue = values[parameterName] as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
        {
            Guid guidValue;

            return Guid.TryParse(stringValue, out guidValue) && (guidValue != Guid.Empty);
        }
    }

    return false;
}}
```

Next when adding the route :

```
routes.MapRoute("doubleGuid", "{controller}/{action}/{guid1}/{guid2}", new { controller = "YourController", action = "YourAction" }, new { guid1 = new GuidConstraint(), guid2 = new GuidConstraint() });
```

Comment: just add a "if (values[parameterName] is Guid) return true;" to catch strongly typed parameters, as for example from tests and for outbound routing ;)

Comment: The performance of the code can be improved by changing "values.ContainsKey" to "values.TryGetValue" and removing the values[parameterName] call.

Comment: But `if (values.ContainsKey(parameterName))` check is really unnecessary, because of a RouteValueDictionary indexer feature - it returns null if the key doesn't exist in the collection [RouteValueDictionary.Item Property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 21):

For **MVC 5** there is already implemented the **GuidRouteConstraint** Class:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routing.constraints.guidrouteconstraint(v=vs.118).aspx

Full list of available MVC constraints: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routing.constraints(v=vs.118).

Comment: This is also available for Web API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routing.constraints.guidrouteconstraint(v=vs.118).aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routing.constraints(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 10):

If you use kazimanzurrashid's code, make sure to include Nikos D's comment. I ended up with this:

```
public class NonEmptyGuidRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, 
        string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
        {
            var guid = values[parameterName] as Guid?;
            if (!guid.HasValue)
            {
                var stringValue = values[parameterName] as string;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
                {
                    Guid parsedGuid;
                    Guid.TryParse(stringValue, out parsedGuid);
                    guid = parsedGuid;
                }
            }
            return (guid.HasValue && guid.Value != Guid.Empty);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Definitely be wary of the code given by @kazimanzurrashid.  It was a good start, but it definitely has a bug or too.  I was passing a real Guid into the route values (instead of a string of a Guid), and I couldn't get anything to match my route.  It took me forever to realize that the *GuidConstraint* was constraining against a real *Guid*, if that makes any sense. :)

Here's what I ended up with, which accepts any data type (not just string), is a bit faster (I think), and contains less *if block* nesting.

```
public class GuidConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        object value;
        if (!values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out value)) return false;
        if (value is Guid) return true;

        var stringValue = Convert.ToString(value);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue)) return false;

        Guid guidValue;
        if (!Guid.TryParse(stringValue, out guidValue)) return false;
        if (guidValue == Guid.Empty) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

+1 @kazimanzurrashid.  Seems spot on.

I'll give an alternative for those who haven't got C#4.0, of which [Guid.TryParse](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94072/guid-tryparse) is part of.  There's another alternative with Regex but [probably not worth the bother.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/09/mastering-guids-with-occams-razor.html)

```
 public class GuidConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
            {
                string stringValue = values[parameterName] as string;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
                {
                    //replace with Guid.TryParse when available.
                    try
                    {
                        Guid guid = new Guid(stringValue);
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return false;
                    }


                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The route constraint for the "alternative with Regex" looks like this:
new { guid = @"^(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}$" }

Comment: Downvoting due to the try {} catch {}. Catching all exceptions is generally regarded as a bad programming practice, and the exception is a performance hit. Use Guid.TryParse to avoid the exception instead.

Comment: @ShadowChaser that's exactly what I said in my answer, TryParse is recommended but only available with C#4.0

Comment: @dove - You're right, I had incorrectly assumed that IRouteConstraint was v4 only.

You can make the code a bit more robust by removing "stringValue = values[parameterName] as string" and changing values.ContainsKey to "values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out value)" then casting it afterwards. The same goes for "catch" - it might be a better idea to swa it for "catch (FormatException) { return false; } catch (OverflowException) { return false; }".

Answer (score 0):

I found that assuming the type is a Guid causes issue when using things like @Html.RouteLink(...) and in Routing tests where the URL is supplied as a string. The code below caters for these situations. Using the above code samples caused issues in my views and/or tests, this below works fine.

```
 public class GuidConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var value = values[parameterName];
        if (value == null) return false;
        var stringValue = value.ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue)) return false;
        Guid guidValue;
        return Guid.TryParse(stringValue, out guidValue) && (guidValue != Guid.Empty);
    }
}
```