# MVC 3 Route resolution question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, routes

I have the following 3 routes

- student/available/classes/{id}
- student/available/classes/{studentId}/{classTypeId}
- student/available/classes/query/{q}

This is how I register the routes in my global.asax.cs file

```
//Student Checkin
routes.MapRoute("StudentAvailableClasses_GetAllForStudent",
            "student/available/classes/{id}",
            new {controller = "StudentCheckin", action = "GetById"});
routes.MapRoute("StudentAvailableClasses_GetClassForStudent",
            "student/available/classes/{studentId}/{classTypeId}",
            new { controller = "StudentCheckin", action = "GetByStudentAndClassType" });
routes.MapRoute("StudentAvailableClasses_Query",
            "student/available/classes/query/{q}",
            new { controller = "StudentCheckin", action = "Query" });
```

When I execute this url

> student/available/classes/query/smith+john

MVC tries to run this route:

> student/available/classes/{studentId}/{classTypeId}

If I reverse the order in which I register the Query route with the GetClassForStudent route, MVC resolves to the query route.

What is going on here, and how can I register these routes with MVC so that they all resolve correctly?

**UPDATE**

Wow, once again thank you to everyone here on stackoverflow! Based on everyone's responses, and in particular the answer by Beno, I now understand my issue, and was able to make it work!

From what I understand, I was not giving MVC enough information about the routes. It was matching the word 'query' into the {studentId} parameter. From Beno's answer I learned about parameter constraints. So now I am able to tell MVC to expect a Guid type in the {studentId} (and {customerId}) parameter.

Here is the code now.

```
    //Student Checkin
    routes.MapRoute("StudentAvailableClasses_GetAllForStudent",
                    "student/available/classes/{id}",
                    new {controller = "StudentCheckin", action = "GetById"},
                    new {id = new GuidConstraint()});
    routes.MapRoute("StudentAvailableClasses_GetClassForStudent",
                    "student/available/classes/{studentId}/{classTypeId}",
                    new {controller = "StudentCheckin", action = "GetByStudentAndClassType"},
                    new {studentId = new GuidConstraint(), classTypeId = new GuidConstraint()});
    routes.MapRoute("StudentAvailableClasses_Query",
                    "student/available/classes/query/{q}",
                    new { controller = "StudentCheckin", action = "Query" });
```

The class [GuidConstraint I found from this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421995/how-can-i-create-a-route-constraint-of-type-system-guid).

Thank you!

Comment: make sure your most specific routes are registered first. Then your more generics ones at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is going on here?

The URL, `student/available/classes/query/smith+john` is correctly picked up by the route `student/available/classes/{studentId}/{classTypeId}` since `{studentID}` can be anything, including 'query'. 'smith+john' is then picked up as the `{classTypeId}`

> how can I register these routes with MVC so that they all resolve correctly?

You could add some validation to the `{studentId}` field. I don't know what your studentId is but if it's an 8 digit number:

```
routes.MapRoute("StudentAvailableClasses_GetClassForStudent",
       "student/available/classes/{studentId}/{classTypeId}",
       new { controller = "StudentCheckin", action = "GetByStudentAndClassType" }
       new { studentId = @"\d{8}" } );
```

**OR**

you could place the `StudentAvailableClasses_Query` route at the top so it gets matched before the other one

**OR**

a combination of both which is probably the best bet

Comment: Awesome! I can tell MVC what type {studentId} is!!! In my particular case I am using guids so there should be a way to describe studentId as guid.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommed running your routes through the [Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx). It will show you exactly where your hangups are.

[image: Route Tester]

Answer (score 0):

Routes resolve in the order in which you register them.  Always register more specific routes before more general routes.

To resolve your issue, move the "StudentAvailableClasses_Query" route to be the first one mapped.

counsellorben