# ASP.Net MVC: Rewriting with routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to map the following URI:

```
/admin/controller/action/id
```

to the following:

```
Controller -> Controller
Action     -> Admin_Action
```

For example:

```
/admin/Users/Create

Controller -> Users
Action  -> Admin_Create

/admin/Users/Delete/1

Controller -> Users
Action -> Admin_Delete(1)
```

Can I achieve that using routing rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following route mapping should work ...

```
 routes.MapRoute("YourRouteName", "admin/controller/action/{id}", new { controller = "Controller", action = "Admin_Action", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think my question was clear. I meant the action should be prepended with admin when there's admin in the URI. (as in my question now)

Comment: In that case I would suggest creating another controller "AdminController" that is used when there is "admin/.." in your route mappings.  Also take a look at using the "Area" functionality ... you should avoid creating Fat Controllers, mainly from a maintainability point of view

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that comment. I'll check into the Area function. I do think that this is actually the answer to what I'm trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Admin",  // Route name
  "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",  // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Controller", action = "Admin_Action", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

But if you want you can also do
www.example.com/admin/

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              
    "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",                     
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

**Update**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminArea",                                              
    "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",                     
    new { controller = "Users", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realised my question was unclear. I've editted it properly now.

Comment: Just change the controller name to Users see Update.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepend names to actions using a `RouteHandler`, as I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563675/differentiate-guid-and-string-parameters-in-mvc-3/7568727#7568727).

If you create a RouteHandler named `AdminHandler` to prepend "Admin_` to your actions, you can then define your route as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute("Admin",  // Route name 
    new Route("admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",  
    new RouteValueDictionary(  
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }),  
        new AdminHandler() 
    ) 
);
```

However, I agree with brodie that you should place all admin actions in a separate Area, as it is a better design, and makes security and maintenance easier.