# Default mvc 5 route with guid id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm trying to setup an mvc 5 attrribute route so that

```
https://localhost/19a6de7e-ee19-43f5-a9c9-8bbdc8dcfc5e
```

routes to /home/index initializing the id param and I cant seem to get it quite right.

I have added routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); to my register routes after the default mapped route

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I have tried a number of things but cant seem to get it to work unless the route is fully defined.

Any advice?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("{id?}")]
    public ActionResult Index(Guid? id)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = id;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now an in-built GuidRouteConstraint() added that would be preferable to using a RegEx.

See [Differentiate Guid and string Parameters in MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563675/differentiate-guid-and-string-parameters-in-mvc-3)

Answer (score 0):

@chrisp_68, you will need a custom route placed before the Default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Just ID",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Then, you need to create an action that takes id as a parameter:

```
public ActionResult IndexID(string id) {
    ...
}
```

Another thing you may consider is constraining the value of id to a guid pattern:

```
    constraints: new { id = @"[a-f0-9-]+" }
```

(Or whatever pattern you need)