# register a ServiceRoute in a mvc application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, wcf-data-services

I am trying to register a service route before any mvc routes.

Is there a way to register it like `product/296eb068-2a1a-439a-b608-6dc0da49cb36`

```
var factory = new DataServiceHostFactory();
var serviceRoute = new ServiceRoute("product/{*guid only}", factory, 
                                     typeof(ProductService));

serviceRoute.Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary { { "serviceType", "odata" }};
serviceRoute.Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary { { "serviceType", "odata"}};

routes.Add("myproduct", serviceRoute);
```

I know `{*guid only}` is not working. Is there a way to make it a regular expression constraint??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote a binder for this and realized you wanted just the route constraint : )

Try this answer:

[How can I create a route constraint of type System.Guid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421995/how-can-i-create-a-route-constraint-of-type-system-guid)

looking at Olivehour's answer:

```
public class NonEmptyGuidRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, 
        string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (values.ContainsKey(parameterName))
        {
            var guid = values[parameterName] as Guid?;
            if (!guid.HasValue)
            {
                var stringValue = values[parameterName] as string;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue))
                {
                    Guid parsedGuid;
                    Guid.TryParse(stringValue, out parsedGuid);
                    guid = parsedGuid;
                }
            }
            return (guid.HasValue && guid.Value != Guid.Empty);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help. I actually find another way to make it work. 
I Created a DynamicServiceRoute class for the ServiceRoute which will allow you to map dynamic route to one single service.

```
public class DynamicServiceRoute
    : RouteBase, IRouteHandler
{
    private string virtualPath = null;
    private ServiceRoute innerServiceRoute = null;
    private Route innerRoute = null;

    public static RouteData GetCurrentRouteData()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            var wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
            return wrapper.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public DynamicServiceRoute(string pathPrefix, object defaults, ServiceHostFactoryBase serviceHostFactory, Type serviceType)
    {
        if (pathPrefix.IndexOf("{*") >= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Path prefix can not include catch-all route parameters.", "pathPrefix");
        }
        if (!pathPrefix.EndsWith("/"))
        {
            pathPrefix += "/";
        }
        pathPrefix += "{*servicePath}";

        virtualPath = serviceType.FullName + "-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "/";
        innerServiceRoute = new ServiceRoute(virtualPath, serviceHostFactory, serviceType);
        innerRoute = new Route(pathPrefix, new RouteValueDictionary(defaults), this);
    }

    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return innerRoute.GetRouteData(httpContext);
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public System.Web.IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        requestContext.HttpContext.RewritePath("~/" + virtualPath + requestContext.RouteData.Values["servicePath"], true);
        return innerServiceRoute.RouteHandler.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

And then you can register the route in the global.asax file

```
var factory = new DataServiceHostFactory();
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new DynamicServiceRoute("nuget/{customername}", null, factory, typeof(Packages)));
```

Here is a blog post from me to read more about it. Cheers

https://kevww.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/implement-dynamic-service-route-for-wcf-just-like-what-you-do-in-mvc/