# ASP.NET Webforms routing, check input types

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, routes, webforms

Say I have a route declaration similar to this in Global.asax:

`RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Products", "products/{productno}/{color}", "~/mypage.aspx");`

How do I configure the route so it only intercepts the request if `{productno}` is a valid Guid and `{color}` is an integer value?

- OK url: */products/2C764E60-1D62-4DDF-B93E-524E9DB079AC/123*
- Invalid url: */products/xxx/123*

The invalid urls will be picked up by another rule/route or just ignored completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own `RouteConstraint` by implementing a matching rule. For example, here's one that makes sure a route parameter is a valid date:

```
public class DateTimeRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, 
        string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        DateTime dateTime;
        return DateTime.TryParse(values[parameterName] as string, out dateTime);
    }
}
```

And then you can enforce it by changing the route definition (this is for MVC 2.0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Edit",
    "Edit/{effectiveDate}",
    new { controller = "Edit", action = "Index" },
    new { effectiveDate = new Namespace.Mvc.DateTimeRouteConstraint() }
);
```

Here are a few more resources:

1. [How can I create a route constraint of type System.Guid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2421995/74757)
2. http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/3/creating_custom_route_constraints_in_asp_net_mvc

Comment: Yeah, it was the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.irouteconstraint(v=vs.100).aspx I was missing. :) Thanks for the pointer...

Answer (score 1):

Short of creating your own `RouteConstraint` the standard routing system supports RegEx route constraints in the standard syntax.  Something like:

```
string guidRegex = @"^(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}$";
string intRegex = @"^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$";

routes.MapRoute(
  "Products",
  "products/{productno}/{color}",
  new { controller = "Products", action = "Index" },
  new { productno = guidRegex, color = intRegex }
);
```