# Rewriting URl containg GUID as query string in Asp.net MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

i am working on Asp net MVC razor web application.
i am trying to implement URL rewriting.

My Urls are like

```
/User/CategoryDetail?cid=2&lid=b20319e0-55b1-4233-8c63-c35b98c79a84
```

but i want it to look like

```
/User/CategoryDetail/[CategoryName]OR[LocationName]
```

Can any once suggest for the solution to implement this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Satpal suggestion is work in case the CategoryName is an optional and LocationName is a mandatory field. In case that both fields are optional, then it doesn't work. Because the routing cannot determine which property is provided. In such case, you have two options. One option is defining 3 different routes for different combination of parameters plus IRouteConstraints,

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "CategoryDetail",
url: "/{controller}/{CategoryDetail}/{LocationName}",
defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Login" },
constraints: {LocationName=@"^\d+$"}
);   

routes.MapRoute(name: "CategoryDetail",
url: "/{controller}/{CategoryDetail}/{CategoryName}",
defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Login" },
constraints: {CategoryName= new GuidConstraint() }
);   

routes.MapRoute(name: "CategoryDetail",
url: "/{controller}/{CategoryDetail}/{LocationName}/{CategoryName}",
defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Login", CategoryName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

for GuidConstraint please visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421995/how-can-i-create-a-route-constraint-of-type-system-guid).