# UrlHelper.Action method not mapping to correct route with first variable parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

Let's look at these two routes mapped in RouteConfig.cs, one with a guid and one without:

```
// Non-guid route
routes.MapPageRoute(
    name: null,
    url: "dashboard/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index" }
);
// Guid route
routes.MapPageRoute(
    name: null,
    url: "{guid}/dashboard/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index" }
);
```

And the method call:

```
UrlHelper.Action("Index", "Dashboard", new { guid = "c73b47b9-4ad5-414a-a92e-8937231f8e2bD" })
```

The method returns this:

```
"/dashboard/?guid=c73b47b9-4ad5-414a-a92e-8937231f8e2b"
```

But I'm expecting this:

```
"/c73b47b9-4ad5-414a-a92e-8937231f8e2b/dashboard/"
```

Note that it's putting the guid as a querystring value instead of the first parameter.

Now if I hardcode that second url the app uses the correct guid route and also works if I use route names instead (UrlHelper.RouteUrl) so I don't think it's an issue with the route mappings themselves.  Neither of these solutions will work well with our application as we have hundreds of routes and currently using UrlHelper.Action all over the place.

I've also tried pretty much every overload and variation of UrlHelper.Action, including passing a RouteValueDictionary instead of an anonymous object.

This is an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application.

Any ideas to why this isn't working? (or alternatives, maybe using one route)

Comment: Your first route is capturing the route you intended to be captured by the second one. Did you try placing the second before the first? You should always go from more specific routes to less specific ones.

Comment: You may have to add a guid contraint as such

[How can I create a route constraint of type System.Guid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421995/how-can-i-create-a-route-constraint-of-type-system-guid)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Put the more specific route first:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "WithGUID",
    url: "{guid}/dashboard/{action}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NoGUID",
    url: "dashboard/{action}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", guid = "" }
);
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! The route engine seems to be going up to the first route in the original example and saying "Hey this route matches just need to throw this "guid" thing at the end".