# DRY principle on MVC project

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a MVC project and I keep repeating the following types of code all over the project.

```
    public ActionResult CompleteTask(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id.HasValue == false)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        Task task = _service.GetTask(id.Value);

        if (task == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
```

is it possible to refactor these null checks?

Answer (score 0):

The first check you can eliminate with proper routing and a [regex constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2430152/60188). The second one you can kind of solve with a custom model binder, so that your action method signature becomes:

```
public ActionResult CompleteTask(Task task)
```

but that would require introducing a bit of ugliness into your `TaskBinder`, since there is no way (that I know of) to terminate request processing from within a custom binder other than throwing an exception and then catching it in your base controller class.